# How do I change the location of my Contacts shell folder?

Tags: windows-7, folder-redirection

I'm using Windows 7. I changed the location of my Contacts folder to "E:\" by accident. Now I cannot change it back. Right clicking the E:\ drive doesn't give me the option to change the location again.

I've tried using regedit.exe to change the entry with a value of "E:\" to "E:\Contacts" but doing so had no effect. I know this because if I attempt to change another shell folders location to "E:\" it warns me that it will be merging with "Contacts".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the desktop and open your User Profile-catalogue, then right click the contacts-folder and select the tab named Placement or similar (using a swe version, so i'm not sure about the eng. translation). Then press the "Move"-button and select your desired folder location.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm just not sure where this User Profile-catalogue is, or how you get to it from the desktop.

Comment: The catalogue should have a symlink either in a profile catalogue on your desktop (named with your account name) or in C:\Users\YourUserAccount